# Django complex query which may need union

Tags: django, django-models

I try to do a complex query in Django through these models.

```
class JobTitleStatus():
    PENDING = 0
    CONFIRMED = 1
    BANNED

class Employer(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     isValidated = models.BooleanField(null=False)
     eminence = models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False,default=4)

class JobTitle(models.Model)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer,null=True,blank=True)
     status = models.IntegerField(null=False, choices=JobTitleStatus)
```

I try to list all validated employers depending on size of their `confirmed` jobtitles.
If there is no `Conmfirmed` jobtitle of an employer it should be at end of the list.

I try to do

```
eList = Employer.objects.filter(name__icontains=emp).filter(isValidated=True)
eList.filter(jobtitle__status=JobTitleStatus.CONFIRMED).annotate(jtt_count=Count('jobtitle')).order_by('-jtt_count','eminence')
```

This query does what I want more or less however, as you expect, employers which doesn't have `Confirmed` job titles are eliminated.

How can I add those `Employers` at the end of that query efficiently ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
eList.annotate(jtt_count=Count('jobtitle')).order_by('jobtitle__status','-jtt_count','eminence')
```

should work, I think.